# GetSearch or SreamListener? python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, python-twitter

I'm very new to twitter api, please help me understand the difference between two things.
As far as I understand I can get real-time tweets by using `tweepy` for example :

```
hashtag = ['justinbieber']
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            data = status.__getstate__()
            print data
            output.write("%s\n "% data)
        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

class Twitter():

    def __init__(self):

        consumer_key=
        consumer_secret=
        access_key = 
        access_secret = 

        self.auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        self.auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
        self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)


    def start(self):
        l = CustomStreamListener()
        stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(self.auth,l, secure=True)
        stream.filter(follow=None, track=hashtag)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Twitter().start()
```

But what exactly I'm getting if I use `python-twitter`'s  `api.GetSearch()`? For example:

```
def t_auth(self):
    consumer_key=
    consumer_secret=
    access_key = 
    access_secret = 

    self.api = twitter.Api(consumer_key, consumer_secret ,access_key, access_secret)
    self.api.VerifyCredentials()

    return self.api

self.tweets = []
self.tweets.extend(self.api.GetSearch(self.hashtag, per_page=10))
```

Imagine that I put last line in an `infinite while loop`, will I get the same result as in the first example? What's the difference between those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my insight.

The first example with `tweepy` stream is a use case of twitter [streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis).
The second example using `python-twitter` is a use case of twitter [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search).

So, I understand this question as: *Should I use twitter regular search API or Streaming API?*

It depends, but, long story short, if you want to see the real real-time picture - you should use streaming.

I don't have enough experience to explain you props and cons of both approaches, so I'll just refer you:

- [Aggregating tweets: Search API vs. Streaming API](http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/aggregating-tweets-search-api-vs-streaming-api/)
- [Search API vs Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10783)
- [Streaming API vs Rest API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960128/streaming-api-vs-rest-api)

Hope that helps.