# event using for autoupdate

Tags: c#, .net, tweetinvi

I have this small code on c# .NET which publish tweets and shows timeline of twitter using tweetinvi . And I'd like to autoupdate timeline whenever the tweet is sent. Can anyone advice how to do it with event? Thanks for answers.

```
private void button1click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            Tweet.PublishTweet(richTextBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Your tweet was sent!", "Important Message");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to write something!", "Important Message");
        }
    }

    private void Timeline_GetHomeTimeline(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    var loggedUser = User.GetLoggedUser();
        string x = "";
        var homeTimelineTweets = loggedUser.GetHomeTimeline();
        foreach (var tweet in homeTimelineTweets)
        {
            x += tweet.Text + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        richTextBox2.Text = x;


    }
```

Comment: Very basically, if you require a near real-time update then you will need to investigate the Streaming API: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

Comment: The following provides some intuition as to how it works: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5960128/2568535

Comment: No, Id like to make it simplier with event, so just when tweet button is pressed it'd execute Timeline_GetHomeTimeline method again, so i get new timeline with tweet just published

Answer (score 0):

First of all please note that it is a very bad practice to make several calls `User.GetLoggedUser();`. The reason being that the endpoint is limited to 15 requests every 15 minutes (1 per minute).

If the user happens to publish more than 15 tweets in 15 minutes, your code will break.

Now you have multiple solutions to solve the problem, but the best one is the `UserStream` (solution 1).

**Solution 1**

I would suggest to add the following code in the `Initialized` event.

```
var us = Stream.CreateUserStream();
us.TweetCreatedByMe += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Update your rich textbox by adding the new tweet with tweet.Text
    var tweetPublishedByMe = args.Tweet;

    // OR Get your timeline and rewrite the text entirely in your textbox
    var userTimeline = Timeline.GetHomeTimeline();
    if (userTimeline != null)
    {
        // foreach ...
    }
};

us.StartStreamAsync();
```

**Solution 2**

If you do not need to reload your `Timeline` each time the user publishes a tweet but you do need the new tweet to be displayed use the following solution.

```
var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("hello");
if (tweet != null)
{
    // Update your rich textbox
}
```

**Solution 3**

Update your `timeline` if a tweet has been published successfully.

```
var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("hello");
if (tweet != null)
{
    var userTimeline = Timeline.GetHomeTimeline();
    if (userTimeline != null)
    {
        // foreach ...
    }
}
```

**NOTE** Please note that I have never had the need to retrieve the `LoggedUser` at any point. Most of the time a `LoggedUser` should be retrieved once and then used across your app.

Also please note that I am the main developer of Tweetinvi.